# Property 'baz' has no initializer but done through a method call in the constructor

Tags: typescript

```
class C {
  foo: number;
  baz: number;

  constructor() {
    this.toto();
    this.foo = 12;
  }

  private toto(): void {
    this.baz = 0;
  }
}
```

The error says:

> TS2564: Property 'baz' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Whereas, it does have an initialize but done through the method toto(). How to avoid to make this raised error?

Comment: Use a non-null assertion on the property: `baz!: number;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typescript compiler is unable to infer that `baz` is set in the constructor, so you will need to use the definite assertion operator (`!`) to assure it that you are setting `baz`.

```js
class C {
  foo: number;
  baz!: number;

  constructor() {
    this.toto();
    this.foo = 12;
  }

  private toto(): void {
    this.baz = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Minor quibble: technically this is the "[definite assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)" operator and not the [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) operator.  They are both post-fix `!` operators, but definite assignment assertions operate on *declarations*, while non-null assertions operate on *expressions*

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix my answer